# Queries about using NumPy Arrays to parse a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

**Q1**: I have a strange issue which I can't seem to figure out.

I'm parsing through a CSV File using the NumPy Module, where a portion of the CSV File (which contains 253 rows and 4 Columns) is shown below:

```
Code            Date       NetPrice   Gain
MICRO US       01/05/2012   613.98   0
MICRO US       01/06/2012   622.75   1.09342432
MICRO US       01/07/2012   690.99  -0.44342342
MICRO US       01/08/2012   611.26  -3.242423423
```

I'm parsing through the CSV File using the code below:

```
micro_info = np.genfromtxt('MICRO.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
```

However, when I run the code below, I get that the first line gives me `(253,)`, but the second line prints the required contents of the CSV File containing all 253 rows and 4 Columns. **I don't understand why this is so**.

```
print micro_info.shape
print micro_info
```

**Q2**: Does what I am doing below make sense?

I'm essentially looking to convert the `Dates` to floats so that I can use `Matplotlib` to plot the `NetPrice` values of `MICRO US` against each `Date`. For this I use the code below:

```
convertingdates = strpdate2num(micro_info[1:,2])
datesasfloat = {1: convertingdates}
micro_info = np.genfromtxt('MICRO.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, converters = datesasfloat, names=True)
```

I will then access the `Dates` and `NetPrice` as required.

Thank You

Comment: Why do you specify `delimiter=','`?  I don't see any ',' in your file sample?

Comment: @hpaulj Its a CSV file, so its `comma` separated I thought.

Comment: If there are no commas it's not comma separated.

Comment: The default delimiter is spaces.  With that it will separate 'US' from 'MICRO', producing 5 fields, not the 4  specified by the 'names'.

Answer (score 3):

With your sample text, this works:

```
In [314]: dconverter=pylab.strpdate2num('%M/%S/%Y')
In [316]: names='code us Date NetPrice Gain'.split()
In [317]: data=np.genfromtxt(ss,skip_header=1,dtype=None,
             converters={'Date':dconverter},names=names)
In [318]: data.shape
Out[318]: (4,)
In [319]: data['Date']
Out[319]: 
array([ 734503.00075231,  734503.00076389,  734503.00077546,
        734503.00078704])
In [320]: data['NetPrice']
Out[320]: array([ 613.98,  622.75,  690.99,  611.26])
```

It uses the default white spaces delimiter.  Because that splits 'MICRO US', I used a custom names list, rather than the header line.  I refined your use of `strpdate2num`.

If the file was comma delimited, then this would work (and using a corrected date converter):

```
In [410]: dconverter=pylab.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')
In [412]: data=np.genfromtxt(ss,names=True,delimiter=',',dtype=None,
                autostrip=True,converters={'Date':dconverter})
In [413]: data
Out[413]: 
array([('MICRO US', 734507.0, 613.98, 0.0),
       ('MICRO US', 734508.0, 622.75, 1.09342432),
       ('MICRO US', 734509.0, 690.99, -0.44342342),
       ('MICRO US', 734510.0, 611.26, -3.242423423)], 
      dtype=[('Code', 'S8'), ('Date', 'O'), ('NetPrice', '<f8'), ('Gain', '<f8')])
```

Another way to deal with 'delimiters' is to give a list of field widths.  For some reason this required an explicit `dtype`.

```
dt=np.dtype([('Code', 'S8'), ('Date', 'O'), ('NetPrice', '<f8'), ('Gain', '<f8')])
data=np.genfromtxt(ss, names=True, delimiter=[15,10,11,12],
    converters={'Date':dconverter}, dtype=dt)
```

Comment: I think you want `'%m/%d/%Y'` as the format string for `dconverter`.